# Can't use SharedPreferences with some checkboxes

Tags: android, android-fragments, checkbox, sharedpreferences

I have a fragment that starts an activity in which I have various checkboxed (Checkbox1, checkbox2 and so on).
I need to keep the status ticked/unticked saved even after I return to the fragment and I start again the activity.

I tried this code but it's not working

```
        final CheckBox checkBox5 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    checkBox5.setChecked(false);

    checkBox5.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (checkBox5.isChecked()) {
                buttonSound.start();
            } else {
                buttonSound.start();
            }
            SharedPreferences pref5 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(.this);                SharedPreferences.Editor editor5 = pref5.edit();
            editor5.putBoolean("checkbox", checkBox5.isChecked());
            editor5.commit();
            if (pref5.getBoolean("checkbox", false) == true){
                checkBox5.setChecked(true);
            } else{
                checkBox5.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });
```

Can anyone enlighten me on what I am doing wrong?

The activity is declared in manifest and I simply want to get back from this Activity to a Fragment and while going from the Fragment to this Activity finding these checkboxes flagged!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about checking if it is actually check?:

```
    if (checkBox5.isChecked()) {
                SharedPreferences pref5 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor5 = pref5.edit();
                editor5.putBoolean("checkbox", checkBox5.isChecked());
                editor5.commit();
        } else {
           // Remove the SharedPreferences here if false
    }
```

If you pass `editor5.putBoolean("checkbox", checkBox5.isChecked());` and is NOT check it (because is not... is currently false) you'll always get **FALSE**.

**EDIT:** Also, please... check the boolean SharedPreference state over the onCreate/onCreateView/onResume or any other place outside that `setOnCheckedChangeListener`.

Comment: And I'd add: What's this?! `if (checkBox5.isChecked()) {
                buttonSound.start();
            } else {
                buttonSound.start();
            }`

Comment: he plays a sound when the user check and uncheck the checkbox lol I'll drive crazy

Comment: or why don't simply store the parameter `isChecked`?

Comment: So... This is enough `buttonSound.start();` without checking. ;)

Comment: yeah... that too @Blackbelt I was lazy to paste that code... true is what he needs.

Comment: I all, I tried it out but it did not work, I now have this code
http://pastebin.com/CbBpABCA
Is it possibly because a Fragment Activity is involved?

Comment: That's because you are not using the correct context. You need "getActivity( ), getApplicationContext or Context" (check my updated answer). Also, if you like, use my SharedPreferences library https://github.com/mkiisoft/KeySaver it works with any context

Comment: Hi Mariano, with the "SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());" I am asked to create a getter and get the red error
Any idea why?
Again, the activity I am working on is a simple Activity but when I return back, I go to a Fragment :/

Comment: I've added more contexts with my answer. If is activity use: ActivityName.this, if Fragment use getActivity (if nothing works, getApplicationContext).

Comment: the mistery goes on :(
getApplicationContext()   no errors but it does not work   http://postimg.org/image/nppf181w1/
.this--->no errors but it does not work     http://postimg.org/image/5ekenvbf3/
getActivity()-->highlighted as red and does not run the app
http://postimg.org/image/anfw52l3p/

You know what's even stranger? the same code works greatly if I just  work with two Activities! But in this current project,  I start from a Fragment, trigger this Activity and then get back to the Fragment :/

Comment: and concerning your last edit, I am doing all the job in the OnCreate, so it should be safe :/

Comment: Just use my library http://github.com/mkiisoft/KeySaver don't mess with your head much longer... I've create it to avoid those issues and to make everything with 1 line of code. Then (if you still want to know whats happen) log your Shared to check if the value is inside that key... if is inside (if "checkbox" is actually true) then, that value will keep alive until you delete the app.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0n0gjpA8
this is my activity. The Boolean "isChecked" works fine because I can hear the sound but the SharedPreferences does not go far.
10 Karma Points to whoever solves this mistery :(

Comment: let me see your library, Mariano. By the way, thanks for helping out.

Comment: @MarcoDeRoni sound will always play because it does by checking and unchecking... doesn't mean anything to be honest. Use Log.e("Any TAG", ""+pref5.getBoolean("checkbox", false)); that will print the value in your logcat. Also: if(pref5.getBoolean("checkbox", false) == true){ System.out.println("yes, it exists!");} over the onResume, onCreate or any place where you can return to that Activity and check the value inside the Shared

Comment: dude... you have a BIG issue. EVERY key is named: "checkbox" you have overriding all the shared preferences! named it differently, please!

Comment: Gracias Mariano. He puesto el primero Log.e y me sale un LogCat largo como la ostia
http://pastebin.com/2zmVT2km
lo que esta en rojo es "E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null"

"E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set"

"E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present"

como puede myView ser null??

Comment: me gusteria ententar tu library: esto "KeySaver.saveShare(Popup1.this, "checkbox", checkBox5.isChecked());" tendria que funcionar, no?

Comment: Exacto, el saveShare debería alcanzar. Por cierto, evita usar "checkbox" como key, usa por ejemplo "checkbox5" o algo que haga que tu key sea única. El Shared va a sobre escribir esa key si la tienes en otro lado. Luego usa KeySaver.getBoolSavedShare(Popup1.this, "checkbox5"); para obtener el valor. Para leer bien tu logcat usa la barra de búsqueda con el TAG que hayas usado. De ese modo sabrás qué respuesta te dio. Además, asegurate de que el logcat esta leyendo tu app y no todo el sistema.

Comment: osea que algo asi tendria que funcionar, no?
http://pastebin.com/u7Mia5bv
Perdona mis errores en espanyol :/

Y si quizas el hecho de que el codigo empieze com "checkBox2.setChecked(false);" sea al problema??
EDIT: Qué locura, no funciona nada :(

Comment: hecho, me veras muy facilmente :)

Comment: @MarcoDeRoni We did it!

Comment: We bloody did it! Ladies and Gentleman, i hereby declare that Mariano Zonilla is a pure genius! Very handy and nice people as well as patient and passionate! He helped me with these sillities he was just great, seriously!

Comment: Hola Mariano, muchas gracias otra vez! Solo un detallito: cuando cierro la app y la abro, los checkboxes estan todavia rellenados, crees que con un @Override public void finish() {
checkBox.setChecked(false);
super.finish;
}
podrìa resolver la situacion, por si acaso? :s